# Execute event onload php file

Tags: php, onclick, popup, modal-dialog, onload

This is the code I have right now and I'd like to execute que script (at the bottom) as soon as the page loads instead of onclick the button.

```html
{capture name=path}
    {l s='Amanpay payment.' mod='amanpay'}
{/capture}

<h1 class="page-heading">
    {l s='Order summary' mod='amanpay'}
</h1>

{assign var='current_step' value='payment'}
{include file="$tpl_dir./order-steps.tpl"}

{if $nbProducts <= 0}
 <p class="alert alert-warning">
        {l s='Your shopping cart is empty.' mod='amanpay'}
    </p>
{else}
        <div class="box cheque-box">
            <h3 class="page-subheading">
                {l s='Amanpay payment.' mod='amanpay'}
            </h3>
            <p class="cheque-indent">
                <strong class="dark">
                    {l s='You have chosen to pay by Amanpay.' mod='amanpay'}
                    {l s='Here is a short summary of your order:' mod='amanpay'}
                </strong>
            </p>
            <p>
                - {l s='The total amount of your order is' mod='amanpay'}
                <span id="amount" class="price">{displayPrice price=$total}</span>
                {if $use_taxes == 1}
                    {l s='(tax incl.)' mod='amanpay'}
                {/if}
            </p>
            <p>
                - {l s='Please confirm your order by clicking "I confirm my order."' mod='amanpay'}.
            </p>
        </div>

        <p class="cart_navigation clearfix" id="cart_navigation">
            {*
         <a 
            class="button-exclusive btn btn-default" 
            href="{$link->getPageLink('order', true, NULL, "step=3")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>{l s='Other payment methods' mod='amanpay'}
            </a>
            *}
            <a  class="button btn btn-default button-medium" href="#" onclick="return confirm(event)">
                <span>{l s='I confirm my order' mod='amanpay'}
                 <i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
                </span>
            </a>
            {*<div style="float: right;margin-top: -38px;">*}
                {$amanpay_widget}
            {*</div>*}
       </p>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function confirm (e)
         {
          e.preventDefault();
                AmnPy.loadModal();
         }
        </script>
{/if}
```

As I said, I need the page to trigger the script onload instead of having to click the confirmation button

Comment: have you tried using window.onload?

Answer (score 1):

Perfect! finally... here was the answer:

```
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            AmnPy.loadModal();
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Solving it yourself is always satisfying